# UILabel cutting off top of text

Tags: ios, text, uibutton, uilabel, clip

I have a UIButton with an UILabel inside that is cutting off the top of my text,
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdnlO.jpg)

The code looks like this:

```
[self.yellowButton setTitle:@"Yellow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.yellowButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Mission Script" size:52.0]];
[self.yellowButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(24.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0)];
```

Changing the frame or bounds of the UILabel doesn't seem to change this as far as I'be been able to tell. Any help would be mega appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried changing the font size?

Comment: @Wain Yeah, it still cuts off the top of the text. It appears that it's an issue with the frame or bounds of the text. If I add a backgroundColor: to the label it shows it cutting off the top but having space at the bottom.